# HDMI Pass through for Audio

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have a stream which I want to cast to a Smart TV. But the streams contains audio format which is not supported by Chromecast as of now.  But the Smart TV is capable for playing this audio format.  Is there anyway I can tell chromecast to do a passthrough for this audio through HDMI?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such functionality in chromecast.